# SVG Icons: How to align icons horizontally in a table

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to align a **clipboard icon** and a **trash icon** side by side inside the  of a table. Help please. Thank you for your time.

Here's what I have but the trash icon appears at the bottom of the clipboard icon.

```html
<td>
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="blue" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2M9 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2m-6 9l2 2 4-4"></path></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"></path></svg>
  </a>
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex` layout to arrange svg icons horizontally on `td`.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td style="display: flex">
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="blue" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2M9 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2m-6 9l2 2 4-4"></path></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"></path></svg>
  </a>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Derek! Awesome. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes. It won't allow me to accept now.

Answer (score 0):

style="Display: Flex" on your cell, and set width on your svg items, you can include in your css

```
td {
display: flex;
}

a {
width: 25px;
}
```